# How are DC offset square wave transmission waveforms generated?

Tags: rs485, serial-bus

The balanced serial transmission shown in the picture is similar to rs485 except that the square wave has a DC offset (e.g. 24VDC) with an alternating offset.

[image: ET-2101]

The transceiver chip "drives" the bus using capacitors that are in series with the bus.

[image: schematic]

How does one generate plus-minus ~3Volt offsets with a 1uF series capacitor? Blue and Purple signals are created this way.

**Edit**: Clarifying the DC offset part.  The bus is powered by a DC power supply (e.g. 24VDC) and an "AC blocking" inductor (which looks like a transformer).

[image: Power Supply]

Comment: Capacitors resist change in voltage. If there was 0v across a cap in series with H+, then suddenly 5v is applied to that cap, then H1 will be forced to 5v. Of course, the cap will charge, and H1 would eventually fall to 0v. But for 20µs (0.00002 seconds), a 1µF cap will not drop much. The resistors and diodes on AIO and BIO try to keep these lines from going above 5.8v and near 0v when inactive, which tends to drain any residual charge off the caps.

Comment: What chip that is, make/model?

Comment: @rdtsc H+ is at 24V, not 5V and never goes to 0V.  The step up and down is ~3V (21V/27V).  I can't see the the arbitrary 3V drop based on 0V across the cap explanation.   The 5.8V zeners are likely to protect the pins.

Comment: Where did the picture and schematic come from?

Comment: Well there must be some missing information somewhere then. HP and HN, if they are the source of 24v, are diode-protected from H+ and H-. With the 5.8v zerners on AIO and BIO, how are H+ and H- ever getting to 24v?

Comment: @rdtsc added more info.  H+ and H- are hooked up to 24VDC power.  I think the magic  is in that weird transformer looking inductor, not the caps. But I'm still stumped as to how the H1 square ware signal is created.